# NSTextField Text Color

Tags: objective-c

Probably a newbie question (I'm a hobbyist, not a programmer) but I can't figure out how to change the text colour for a NSTextField. I have such a field that is inactive still a certain event occurs, then I want to display a prompt red text prompt in the field then change the text colour to black so that when the user enters the info it appears in black. Can this be done?
Thanks,
Keith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code would set your UITextField color to red.

```
[yourTextfield setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

When your event occurs you can use the same syntax to set it back to blackColor.

Comment: Hi, when I used your suggestion I got the error "Unknown receiver 'UIColor'; did you mean ;CIColor'?" and I don't know what this means.

Comment: Ah I see yes so thats for OSX then. UIColor is for iOS.